# Selecting last child with specific id

Tags: select, html

So here is the thing:

```
<div id="wrapper" > <div id="x"></div ><div id="x"></div ><div id="x"></div><div id="y"></div>
</div>
```

So how do i select last div with id=x  not y inside of wrapper? Sorry , but i dont know how to pase code to be visible.

Comment: You should not and can not use the same id multiple times as an `id` is a unique identifier of an element. What you want to use instead of `id` is `class`.

Answer (score 1):

An ID is unique so to select it you should just be using

```
#x {}
```

I would question why you are using multiple id's though, maybe a class would be better?

*Edit*
Just noticed you pasted some code.

You really shouldn't be using ID's the way you are, you need to be using classes replace your id's with:

```
class="x"
```

If only for modern browsers you can use the last-of-type selector

```
.x:last-of-type
```

if going back to IE6 you can always add a class like last and then select it

```
class="x last"

.x.last {}
```

*Edit* For question

To use your wrapper selection you add it to the front of your selector:

```
#x .x.last {
    /** css goodness here **/
}
```

Comment: ad(.x:last-of-type) - yes, but how to use it with wrapper selector?

Comment: As-long as you learn from them there are no bad mistakes (within reason).